# How to plot a barchart with more than one Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, yaxis

Hi everybody i got this dataset:

```
     | Campaign | #Users | Country |
     |:-------  |:------:|  ------:|
     | Ongoing  | 150    | MX      |
     | Canceled | 130    | USA     |
     | Paused   | 120    | CH      |
```

And I would like to make a barchart where campaign is equal to the x-axis , then represent the numbers of users as Y-axis and fill country as color.

I got something like this but i cannot add an extra axis

```
ggplot(data=camopaign, mapping(aes(x=campaign , y =Users, fill = country)) + geom_bar()
```

Thanks for everything

Comment: Your code as it stands doesn't work. It should be `ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=Campaign , y =Users, fill = Country)) + geom_bar(stat= "identity")` where `mydf` is whatever you named your dataframe. Otherwise, I'm not clear on what you mean by "more than one y axis". If you mean having another axis label on the right hand side, see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

Comment: You can also use `geom_col()` as a shortcut for `geom_bar(stat= "identity")`.

Comment: What information do you want to show on the extra axis ?